# Is it possible to force a static method to return an object of the same type its own class?

Tags: typescript

I'd like that a static method was forced to return an instance of object that type is the type of its class.

For example:

```js
abstract class AbstractInstance {

    static getOwnInstance(): this {
        return new (this as any);
    }
}

class C1 {
    
}

class C2 extends AbstractInstance {
    
    static getOwnInstance(): C1 { //=> this method should return an instance of "C2" type
        return new C1;
    }

}
```

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/WGGRMW) maybe? It's important to note that `C1` and `C2` must be structurally distinct (and not be empty, `{}`) for any solution to this to work, since TypeScript is structurally typed.

Comment: @merryweather No. `AbstractInstance<C1>` would break what I want.
I know TS structurally typed, but my problem is related to the method signature, not with the structure of the class itself, I mean, with members that it must structurally have.

Comment: I don't understand why you're overriding `getOwnInstance` in the first place, since `new this` will always do what you want, even in subclasses.  Even if you get this working, `class C3 extends C2 { newProp = 1 }` will cause `C3.getOwnInstance()` to return `C2`, not `C3`.  And that means your typing for `getOwnInstance()` needs to be generic all the way down.  Like, you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn5gqw).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz `return new this` was just an example. I want a type that force a retrun method signature be always of an instance of own class. So `generics` can't be used. Got it? `static getOwnInstance(): OwnInstance<self> | self { ... }`

Comment: The only thing that makes sense is `return new this`.  If you write `return new C2` inside `C2`'s `getOwnInstance()` method, then any subclass of `C2` will automatically *fail* to meet your requirement, because it will only return a `C2` and not the new subclass.  I gave an example in my previous comment.  The only thing that's safe is to use generics. I can't tell if you've understood this issue or not.   ... (edit: I'm afraid I don't understand `OwnInstance<>` or `self` in your edited comment; what are you saying?)

Comment: @jcalz Yeap, I got it this problem. But `return new this` is only a part of the solution. If a member of a any class try to override the method `getOwnInstance`, I wish TS wouldn't let it do anything other than `return new this`, like `return new C1`, `return new C2`,... maybe the method `getOwnInstance` of `AbstractInstance` there should be a return type in its signature that prevents this. I proposed `OwnInstance` as example. Get it?

Comment: Please look at [my suggestion from before](https://tsplay.dev/Nn5gqw) and show me exactly where your problem with it is.  It essentially only lets you write `return new this` (not `return new C1` or `return new C2` because those are not safe), which is, I think, the only safe thing you can do.  You said before "generic can't be used" but I'm failing to understand why.  You essentially want there to be a static polymorphic `this` type as suggested in [ms/TS#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863), but that isn't part of TS, so I'm suggesting the standard workaround.

Comment: @jcalz you resolve my problem : ) I haven't seen it before because I was with only my cellphone. I take my notebook to test your solution.
You managed to ensure a secure signature for the `getOwnInstance` method.
I'm very happy.
Thank so much.
I didn't know this `this: new (...args: any) => ...` syntax. So this creates a polymorphic `this`, as the discussion says. That's right?

Comment: It emulates a polymorphic `this` by using a generic `this` parameter.  I'll explain fully in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is a [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) that works for [`static`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members) methods.  Unfortunately that feature is not part of TypeScript.  There's a longstanding open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) for this, but for now we need to work around it.

The standard workaround first seems to be mentioned in [this comment on ms/TS#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-242782664), where we use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter along with a [`this` *parameter*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters), in order to emulate polymorphic `this`:

```
abstract class AbstractInstance {
    a = 1 // added some structure to avoid empty class issues
    static getOwnInstance<T extends AbstractInstance>(this: new () => T) {
        return new this;
    }
}
```

Here, you can only call `getOwnInstance()` on an object whose type is a zero-arg constructor returning some type `T` constrained to `AbstractInstance`.  And then since it returns `new this`, the return type of the method is `T`.

So, first of all, that means you can't call it on the abstract constructor itself, because it isn't directly `new`able:

```
AbstractInstance.getOwnInstance(); // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

And subclasses will automatically get the appropriate return type:

```
class C1 extends AbstractInstance {
    b = 2
}
const c1 = C1.getOwnInstance();
//    ^? const c1: C1
c1.b.toFixed(); // okay
```

If you try to override `getOwnInstance()`, you essentially are forced to do it the same way as the original implementation, in the sense that call signature and return type can't really be any more specific:

```
class C2 extends AbstractInstance { // error!
    //~~
    /* Class static side 'typeof C2' incorrectly extends 
    base class static side 'typeof AbstractInstance'.
    The types returned by 'getOwnInstance()' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'C2' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'C2' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be
    instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AbstractInstance 
    */
    c = 3
    static getOwnInstance() {
        return new C2(); // <-- oops!
    }
}
```

That failed because `C2` isn't known to be appropriate. Indeed if you *subclass* `C2`, then you really don't want `C2`:

```
class C3 extends C2 {
    d = 4;
}
C3.getOwnInstance() // should be C3, not C2
```

So you're constrained to implementing it more or less without alteration:

```
class C4 extends AbstractInstance {
    e = 5
    static getOwnInstance<T extends AbstractInstance>(this: new () => T) {
        console.log("okay I guess");
        return new this;
    }
}
```

So that looks good.

---

This workaround isn't *perfect*. It would be nice if you could plausibly constrain, say, `T` in `C4.getOwnInstance()` to `C4` instead of `AbstractInstance`, which is what you'd get for free with a true polymorphic `this` type.  And adding extra generics where you weren't trying to use them is possibly confusing.  So hopefully one day ms/TS#5863 will be addressed and there will be a more appealing approach.  For now, though, this is about the best we can do.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacIEkA7SYQ2AUwQG8BYAKAUYWAQF4EBGephEiAS1gIA5uQgB5AO6EiJMuQA8AFQTkAHhHKEAJhmyQY8WRFIUAfAAoIAC35gAXAkLlJCCwEo2ZhEs+0GPExQYgCuUIROLgg2dgDc3EwAvvTJdPT6uEbEJvIAdKIS0sam5B6xCAD0FapQUAD2UACE9FUAfu0dnZ0t1QDCpIR1iGhg-MIRpMw4hoiwddlQIfAN0QCeAA6UEHXMTvMAtKAGeEjzBkvbUGubufR3dCgjCL0cqhpauljTeMXy1AmMEBsBAAJhS9Dm2SQr3YL3yYikMmyJTKPR4AD0APynKGwDiOF4Qji5EC5bYAMX4anI2jKlWqdQA1sBVvcIah0M8QW9NDo9N8snIKNR6TV6k0AfT2pKKgAqZ4cjB8QS8fjaSgAcggG3IdQAZlyNQh+GQGsF4MhVjyPhhJSA0JRHpzlUJRuqEFqdfqvsdBTkKBrbgFGEprFsdRhghAws5tAgQFaNQVEb8KB4jcBgsbTQBbdbAAQgZCUEBiSTkLTRMNgcObMBBnhKHUe3ogo12PbDdBjQigYvRHbazYepSByUa1vtjAjHt9raDsM444mxDeoea0cAGnjIUQGtHpxCyDjpclJrkAgLNIQkn4Nl22n4er15GChEQYBCIHXCG9kOX74ehkMyppQkqyhUbLBkgwIAMySi6IgIkUyLyB4-zQTwUYxpEritnSVQIAo+z7L+dTrGAzTQakqTsk8vSwdafJchhPBxuwAAs8R0KkDHwoUSJCqUniEWA1h1EeJ6UAx26DIgrb3E6GC9BxTGfMBPyocK-g8JQ7AAKwISYAhCMmKFCcoan8r6BBaeQlgxA4uFuJ4rDeL4rGBIw-51MWuTIHUwgWAAREyLIIPgIghOQ6DBe43FeYw2HhM5jkJUk4J0EAA)